# Relative layout views not shrinking down on smaller screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity that hosts a fragment and a Button, the fragment should take the majority of the screen while the button should take a small part of the lower part of the screen.
However I can't make the Relative layout shrink down so that the button doesn't overlap over the fragment.

below is my activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_registration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.activities.RegistrationActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragments.registration.GenderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/profile_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="BUTTON TEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and below is the layout of the fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.fragments.registration.GenderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/xlarge_top_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/bienvenido" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender_explanation"
        style="@style/HeaderTitleWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_note"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="WELCOME TO THE APP"
        android:textSize="@dimen/header_title_text_view_xtra_big_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gender_avatar_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_top_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/woman"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/man"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        style="@style/AppButtonMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_avatar_holder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_top_margin"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

below is a screenshot of how it looks

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Your frangment content is too big, so you should user ScrollView inside your layout, like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.fragments.registration.GenderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/xlarge_top_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/bienvenido" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender_explanation"
        style="@style/HeaderTitleWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_note"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="WELCOME TO THE APP"
        android:textSize="@dimen/header_title_text_view_xtra_big_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gender_avatar_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_top_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/woman" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/man" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        style="@style/AppButtonMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gender_explanation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_avatar_holder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_top_margin"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ok, but is there a way to make this work without a scrollview in a way to make the content of relative layout shrink to fit?

Comment: @Fouad the way is create layouts for all densities.

Comment: do you mean I should create different layouts for different screen sizes or use dp and sp units?

Comment: i mean use layouts for different screen sizes, but in my opinion the right way is use ScrollView